# Remove duplicates based on rank after join in SQL request

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL 5.6.
I have a SQL table with a list of users:

```
id name
1  Alice
2  Bob
3  John
```

and a SQL table with the list of gifts for each user (numbered in order of preference):

```
id gift       rank
1  balloon    2
1  shoes      1
1  seeds      3
1  video-game 1
2  computer   2
3  shoes      2
3  hat        1
```

And I would like a list of the preferred gift for each user (the highest rank - if two gifts have the same rank, pick only one randomly) (bonus: if the list could be randomized, that would be perfect!):

```
id name  gift     rank
2  Bob   computer 2
1  Alice shoes    1
3  John  hat      1
```

I tried to use the clause GROUP BY but without any success.

Comment: what engine do you use?

Comment: I am using MySQL !

Comment: @klaus always add the correct tags to question so people looking at specific filters can see it

Comment: Ok, my bad. The type of the database is InnoDB.

Comment: What MySQL version are you running? Ranking has become easy with MySQL 8.

Comment: I am not sure about the version I am running. I am using PhpMyAdmin interface on a dedicated web server (I believe it is an "old" version, maybe 5.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering rank as a part of your data; Without using window functions or complex sub queries

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, g.gift
FROM users u
JOIN gifts g ON g.id = u.id
LEFT JOIN gifts g2 ON g2.id = g.id AND g2.rank > g.rank
WHERE g2.id IS NULL;
```

Added link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62f59e/15/0

Comment: It is not working. I have duplicated names and "rank" column is full of "NULL"...

Comment: ignore the columns on right; removed only see first 3 @klaus

Comment: Ok. On your example, you have to switch from g2.rank > g.rank to g2.rank < g.rank

Comment: And if I add "insert into gifts values (1, "video game", 1);" i end up with two lines for Alice... I would like only one... how could you do this ?

Comment: @klaus Then you can group by ID and it will show only 1

Comment: I also added ORDER BY RAND() to randomize the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number` to get one row for each User.(Mysql 8.0+)

```
SELECT A.ID,NAME,GIFT,`RANK` FROM USERS A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ID,GIFT,`RANK` FROM 
        (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY `RANK` ASC) AS RN  FROM X) X
    WHERE RN =1
) B 
ON A.ID= B.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know DB what you use. And I'm not an expert in SQL(I can have some mistake in next). But I think it is not difficult.

So I can give you just advice that you have to think gradually. Let me write.

First All I need is the highest rank. So I have to get this.

```
SELECT  MAX(RANK)
FROM    GIFT
GROUP BY ID
```

And then I think that I need get gifts from this rank.

```
SELECT GIFT.*
FROM   GIFT
INNER JOIN(
  SELECT ID, MAX(RANK)
  FROM GIFT
  GROUP BY ID
) filter ON GIFT.ID = filter.ID AND GIFT.RANK = filter.RANK
```

I think this is the table what you want!

So If below code works, That's what you really want.

```
SELECT *
FROM USER
LEFT OUTER JOIN(
  above table
) GIFT ON USER.ID = GIFT.ID
```

But Remember this, I said I'm not an expert in SQL. There can be better way.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Attached Image]
Checkout the query

```
SELECT tbluser.id,name,gift,rank into tblrslt
FROM tbluser 
LEFT JOIN tblgifts
ON tbluser.id = tblgifts.id  order by id,rank;

SELECT tt.*
FROM tblrslt tt
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT id, min(rank) AS rank
    FROM tblrslt
    GROUP BY id) groupedtt 
ON tt.id = groupedtt.id 
AND tt.rank = groupedtt.rank order by id
```

Comment: Please check out the Image ... I believe  this would work ..

Comment: I have the following error:  #1327 - Undeclared variable: tblrslt :(

Comment: Please checkout fiddle   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5ad59/19

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL versions older than 8 you have no ranking functions available. You'll select the minimum rank per user instead and use these ranks to select the gift rows. This means you access the gifts table twice.

I suggest this:

```
select *
fron users u
join gifts g 
  on g.id = u.id 
  and (g.id, g.rank) in (select id, min(rank) from gifts group by id)
order by u.id;
```

If you also want to show users without gifts, simply change the inner join to a left outer join.

Comment: I tried your request but if I have several gifts with the same rank (let's say for Alice "shoes" with rank 1 and "video-game" with rank 1) I will end up with two entries for Alice but I want only one

Comment: And all my rank column is "NULL"

Comment: Ah, okay. You didn't mention that there can be two gifts with the same rank for a user. You should add this explantion to your request and also add such a case to your sample data.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My bad. I updated the sample.